# Create a web app project that is linked to firebase analytics in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I created a web app and wanted to enable the analytics using api in C# library. I implemented it as follows :

```
    public static void CreateWebProject()
{
        
    var body = new WebApp()
    {
     DisplayName = "mywebapp-fromapi5",
               
    };
    var operationWeb1 = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.WebApps.Create( body, "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();

    var analytics = new AddGoogleAnalyticsRequest {
                
        AnalyticsAccountId = "248540946"

    };

    var operationWeb2 =  _firebaseManagementService.Projects.AddGoogleAnalytics(analytics, "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();
    WaitOperation(operationWeb1, nameof(WebApp));

    WaitOperation(operationWeb2, nameof(WebApp));

}
```

But as I run the code, I get the below error:

```
Unhandled exception. The service firebase has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request contains an invalid argument. [400]
Errors [
    Message[Request contains an invalid argument.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service firebase has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Request contains an invalid argument.
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Comment: If it's a webapp, why do you use firebase? You use the JS-based GA4 tracking for web apps. Either gtag.js or GTM.

Comment: I wanted to implement the firebase configurations programmatically using c# api instead of manually going to the firebase console to create the web app and enable the analytics.

Comment: Ok, that's not how you do it. First of all, you don't need firebase. The only real use case for firebase is when you can comfortably use its SDK in an app to then connect it to GA4 and use the data in GA4. For the rest of the clients, you either do web tracking directly into GA4 through GTM/gtag.js, or you use a measurement protocol if you don't have JS context in the app. But you do, on the front-end, if it's really a web app.

Comment: Yes BNazaruk, I did the tracking of the activities/events on the web using angular gtag, but here my plan was to setup the backend configuration related to firebase ( the rules, the analytics, cloud project setup....) programmatically on server using firebase management api in c# instead of to manually creating it on the console, like the procedure written in google doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project?platform=android

Comment: For parallel backend tracking we use the server-side GTM and its router to send events to wherever, including Firebase.

Comment: Yes that is right BNazaruk,but what I wanted to implement was not the tracker, I wanted to setup higher level project setup programmatically.Creating a firebase project, firebase web apps with analytics feature enabled,I am interested in getting the web config parameters which are apiKey, authDomain, projectId, storageBucket, messagingSenderId, appId,  and  especially the measurementId. Since I was  using the firebase management api in C# to create the web app, and it didn't link the analytics by default so I was supposed to use  AddGoogleAnalytics method to get the measurementId parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the method was first called, it enabled the analytics and linked the Default Account for Firebase for the specific firebase project I used. However, when I tried to link the newly created firebae apps under the same Firebase project by calling the method again, it raised an error, because it is enabled for the firebase project/parent, and there is no need to enable it for the other created firebase apps/child if they are under the same firebase. project.

To make it clear, I am trying to use .NET libraries of google and firebase  to programmatically setup google cloud project, firebase project, firebase web app with analytics enabled.